# Updating a DLL used in several projects

Tags: c#, windows, dll, gac

I have a DLL with tools i use in several projects. The DLL is frequently updated with new functions. How can i automate the replacement of the DLL in a way so that i dont have to manually copy and paste?

The way i do it now is that i build my project with visual studio, manually copy the DLL file from bin/debug folder and paste them into the root folder of the different projects that use it.

I know gacutil is used to register DLLs to the GAC and that i can make a batch file that does this.

If i install it to the GAC and the projects reference them there, will they be updated? What typicall options are there?

Comment: either `<ProjectReference>` or `<PackageReference>`, job done?

Comment: Don't use the GAC.

Comment: @Aron why not use the GAC?

Comment: @Daarwin State. Its one more thing you have to control in your deployment. If your deployment method is some form of xcopy, success rates goes up and unknowns go down.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into packaging the library as a NuGet package.

If that doesn't work for you, there's post-build events in Visual Studio that you can use so that the copy & paste is done automatically for you.